# Show that $a\sin 2\alpha+b\sin 2\beta+c\sin 2\gamma=0$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If the internal bisectors of the angles of the triangle ABC make angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ with sides $a,b,c$ respectively then show that $a\sin 2\alpha+b\sin 2\beta+c\sin 2\gamma=0$

I tried to solve it.Let internal bisector $AI$ make angle $\beta$ with side $b$ and angle $\gamma$ with side $c$,let internal bisector $BI$ make angle $\alpha$ with side $a$,angle $\gamma$ with side $c$,internal bisector $CI$ make angle $\alpha$ with side $a$,angle $\beta$ with side $b$.

$\angle A=\beta+\gamma,\angle B=\alpha+\gamma,\angle C=\alpha+\beta$

$a\sin 2\alpha+b\sin 2\beta+c\sin 2\gamma=2R(\sin A\sin 2\alpha+\sin B\sin 2\beta+\sin C\sin2\gamma)=2R(\sin(\beta+\gamma)\sin 2\alpha+\sin(\alpha+\gamma)\sin 2\beta+\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin2\gamma)$

I tried to further simplify it using $2\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma=\pi$ but could not achieve final result.Is my approach right?Please help me reach the final answer.

Comment: Let $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ be the internal bisectors. Then, you have $\alpha$ is an angle between $AD$ and $BC$ (which is $a$ as usual), $\beta$ is an angle between $BE$ and $CA$ and $\gamma$ is an angle between $CF$ and $AB$. Do you understand?

Comment: Hint: you may try $\sin 2\alpha=1-\sin^2 \alpha$.

Comment: @GAVD,how to proceed ahead with this method,Sir?

Comment: Let me correct your points. The internal bisector $AI$ make an angle $\frac{A}{2}$ with the side $b$ and $c$, not $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: @GAVD,I got the answer,thank you Sir.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia If you found the answer to your question, please consider self-answering it. If you do, don't forget to accept you own answer, so it gets removed from the unanswered tab.